# Uncaught SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Tags: javascript, php, rest

So I'm building a social network as a personal hobby but, recently, when I try to Like a post the console log returns that error above. The code was working just fine in the last days but out of no where this error popped up.

Restapi code for liking a post:

```
if ($_GET['url'] == "likes") 
           {
                   $postId = $_GET['id'];
                   $token = $_COOKIE['SNID'];
                   $likerId = $db->query('SELECT  user_id FROM tokens WHERE token=:token', array(':token'=>sha1($token)))[0]['user_id'];
   
                   if (!$db->query('SELECT user_id FROM post_likes WHERE post_id=:postid AND user_id=:userid', array(':postid'=>$postId, ':userid'=>$likerId))) {
                           $db->query('UPDATE posts SET likes=likes+1 WHERE id=:postid', array(':postid'=>$postId));
                           $db->query('INSERT INTO post_likes VALUES (\'\', :postid, :userid)', array(':postid'=>$postId, ':userid'=>$likerId));
                           //Notify::createNotify("", $postId);
                   } else {
                           $db->query('UPDATE posts SET likes=likes-1 WHERE id=:postid', array(':postid'=>$postId));
                           $db->query('DELETE FROM post_likes WHERE post_id=:postid AND user_id=:userid', array(':postid'=>$postId, ':userid'=>$likerId));
                   }
                        
                    echo "{";
                    echo '"Likes":';
                    echo $db->query('SELECT likes FROM posts WHERE id=:postid', array(':postid'=>$postId));
                    echo "}";
           }
```

script desing:

```
$.ajax({

                        type: "GET",
                        url: "restapi/posts",
                        processData: false,
                        contentType: "application/json",
                        data: '',
                        success: function(r) {
                                var posts = JSON.parse(r)
                                $.each(posts, function(index) {
                                        $('.timelineposts').html(
                                                $('.timelineposts').html() + ' <li class="list-group-item" id="'+posts[index].postId+'" style="border-color: #cbcbcb;"><blockquote class="blockquote"><p class="mb-0" style="color: rgb(0,0,0);">'+posts[index].PostBody+'</p><footer class="blockquote-footer">Posted by '+posts[index].PostedBy+' on '+posts[index].PostDate+'</footer></blockquote><button data-id="'+posts[index].postId+'" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" style="background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);color: rgb(0,0,0);width: 142px;font-family: Alegreya, serif;"  >&nbsp;<i class="icon-fire" data-bs-hover-animate="rubberBand" style="color: rgb(36,0,255);" ></i>&nbsp;'+posts[index].Likes+' likes</button><button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" style="background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);color: rgb(0,0,0);width: 142px;font-family: Alegreya, serif;" onclick="showCommentsModal()" data-postid="'+posts[index].postid+'" >&nbsp;<i class="typcn typcn-pencil" data-bs-hover-animate="rubberBand" style="color: rgb(255,0,0);"></i>&nbsp;Comentários</button>  </li> </ul>  '
                                        )

                                        $('[data-postid]').click(function() {
                                                var buttonid = $(this).attr('data-postid');

                                                $.ajax({

                                                        type: "GET",
                                                        url: "restapi/comments?postid=" + $(this).attr('data-postid'),
                                                        processData: false,
                                                        contentType: "application/json",
                                                        data: '',
                                                        success: function(r) {
                                                                var res = JSON.parse(r)
                                                                showCommentsModal(res);
                                                        },
                                                        error: function(r) {
                                                                console.log(r)
                                                        }

                                                });
                                        });

                                        $('[data-id]').click(function() {
                                                var buttonid = $(this).attr('data-id');
                                                $.ajax({

                                                        type: "POST",
                                                        url: "restapi/likes?id=" + $(this).attr('data-id'),
                                                        processData: false,
                                                        contentType: "application/json",
                                                        data: '',
                                                        success: function(r) {

                                                                var ress = JSON.parse(r)
                                                                
                                                                $("[data-id='"+buttonid+"']").html(' <i class="icon-fire" data-bs-hover-animate="rubberBand" style="color: rgb(36,0,255);"></i>&nbsp; '+ress.likes+' likes</span>')
                                                        },
                                                        error: function(r) {
                                                                console.log(r)
                                                        }

                                                });
                                        })
                                })

                        },
                        error: function(r) {
                                console.log(r)
                        }

                });

        });
```

Already verify all queries and they work fine in the sql.

EDIT::

[image]

Comment: Please don't ever try to create your own JSON string. Instead, create an array with your data, then use [`json_encode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to make sure the json is created properly

Comment: To verify exactly what is being returned, check your Network tab for the response from the server.

Comment: @aynber it returns this ```http://localhost/site/restapi/likes?id=112``` which is good since it is the right postid but the JSON.parse wont let me change the number of likes

Comment: That's the URL it returned from. Click on that, then click on the Response tab to see what is being returned.

Comment: @aynber **This Request has no response data available.** So the problem is in the api...

Comment: Sometimes that happens when the response is old. Refresh the page and try again.

Comment: OK, I see it now, I have a lot of errors in the api code, I need to fix them... i UPDATE the thread

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
echo"<pre>";print_r($_GET); exit();
```

and see if you get any data in the backend

when you send data form the backend, do so in the following format

```
function listOfComments(){
 $response=[
  "success"=>0,
  "message"=>"",
  "data"=>[]
 ];

 //database queries

 if($databaseResponse){
   $response=[
    "success"=>1,
    "message"=>"",
    "data"=>$databaseResponse
   ];
 }else{
   $response["message"]=>"No Data"
 }
 return json.encode($response);
}
```

On the front end in javascript you could do

```
var ress = JSON.parse(r);
if(ress.success){
  // render UI
}else{
alert(ress.message);
}
```

I'd be willing to help you out if you could share the link to your git hub repo.
Use https://json2html.com/ to render data on the front end.
Use onClick event on a class and not a custom attribute.

Comment: Im confused, the ```function ListOfComments()``` is supposed to be the like posts?

Comment: https://github.com/pedroPereira18/SocialNewtork heres my github... Look at the pages homepage.html  and index.php(inside restapi)

Comment: `function ListOfComments()` returns comments for a particular post. the `$response` array is how you should return data to the front end. `$response["data"]` should be an array of comments for a post. if that data exist then set `$response["success"] = 1` .